# Свой иконки для начала и конца маршрута?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

this._yMap - this.handleApiAvaliable
this._mapElement - ref

Пробовал два варианта никак не получается кастомизация

Через точки:

```
addRoute = (startPoint, endPoint) => {
if (this._yMap && this._mapElement) {
    this._yMap.route(
        [
            startPoint,
            endPoint
        ],
        {
            mapStateAutoApply: true
        }
    )
        .then(route => {
            this._route = route;

            this._route.getPaths().options.set({
                strokeColor: "fa6600",
                opacity: 0.9
            });

            const points = this._route.getWayPoints(),
                  lastPoint = points.getLength() - 1;

            points.get(0).properties.set('iconLayout', 'default#image');
            points.get(0).properties.set('iconImageHref', objectMap);
            points.get(0).properties.set('iconImageSize', [33, 40]);
            points.get(0).properties.set('iconImageOffset', [-16, -20]);

            this._mapElement.geoObjects.add(route);
        })
}
};
```

Задание options всего маршрута

```
addRoute = (startPoint, endPoint) => {
if (this._yMap && this._mapElement) {
    this._yMap.route(
        [
            startPoint,
            endPoint
        ],
        {
            mapStateAutoApply: true
        }
    )
        .then(route => {
            this._route = route;

            this._route.getPaths().options.set({
                strokeColor: "fa6600",
                opacity: 0.9
            });

            this._route.getWayPoints().options.set({
                wayPointStartIconLayout: 'default#image',
                wayPointFinishIconLayout: 'default#image',
                wayPointStartIconImageHref: objectMap,
                wayPointFinishIconImageHref: objectMapSelected,
                wayPointStartIconImageSize: [33, 40],
                wayPointFinishIconImageSize: [49, 60]
            });

            this._mapElement.geoObjects.add(route);
        })
}
};
```

Не так, не так результатов нет ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В песочнице JS API есть [пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_view_options) реализации вашей задачи.